# Java choose whether to add or subract

Tags: java, addition, subtraction

My question is simple why ddoesnt  add if I choose  + m and subtract if I  choose -

All help is appreciated here. thanks in advance, What I am doing wrong here , I know I am on the right track

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int tal1, tal2;
    char operator;

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Write in a 1st integer");
    tal1 = input1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Write in 2nd intger");
    tal2 = input2.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Do you want to add or subtract please choose + or -");
    operator = (char) input3.nextInt();

    if (operator == '-') {
        System.out.println("Tal1 - Tal2 = " + (tal1 - tal2));
    } else if (operator == '+') {
        System.out.println("Tal1 + Tal2 = " + (tal1 + tal2));
    }

    System.out.println("Wrong thing to do buddy");

}
```

Comment: Why so many Scanners? One is enough. Also `-` or `+` is not int so you cant use `nextInt` to get this. Consider using `next` and storing result in String. Also remember to compare strings with `equals` not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

use `next()` instead of `nextInt()` and use String instead of char and compare the Strings with `str_1.equals("+")` this returns true if strings are matched

Answer (score 0):

Okey Friend:

You hav two errors:

1- You havent started a class before public static void main.

2- You have an error in this line.

```
operator = (char)input3.nextInt();
```

'+' ans '-' are not int. So you cannot get an int for them.

Instead use the following code which I have written for you:

```
class Test2
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{


int tal1, tal2;
char operator;

Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner input2 = new Scanner (System.in);
Scanner input3 = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Write in a 1st integer");
    tal1=input1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Write in 2nd intger");
    tal2=input2.nextInt();




    System.out.println("Do you want to add or subtract please choose + or -");
    operator = input3.nextLine().charAt(0);




    if (operator == '-')
    {
        System.out.println("Tal1 - Tal2 = "+(tal1-tal2)); 
    }

    else if (operator == '+')
    {

            System.out.println("Tal1 + Tal2 = "+(tal1+tal2)); 
    }

        System.out.println("Wrong thing to do buddy");
}


}
```